# View Google maps inside Tkinter app

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have the following function in python,

```
def in_out(lat,lon,api_key):
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=" + api_key + "&center="+ str(lat) + "," + str(lon) + "&zoom=20&format=png&maptype=roadmap&style=element:labels%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:administrative\
        %7Celement:geometry%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:administrative.neighborhood%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:landscape.man_made%7Csaturation:90\
        %7Clightness:-5%7Cvisibility:simplified%7Cweight:8&style=feature:poi%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:road%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:road%7Celement:labels.icon\
        %7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:transit%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:water%7Cvisibility:off&size=" + str(dim)
    display(im(requests.get(url).content))
```

When we pass an lat, long along with google API key, it gives us a image of the map.

For eg,

```
in_out(47.6935488,-122.1332999, api_key)
```

gives the following,

[image]

Now I want to display the image inside the TKinter app. The following is the code that I have written,

```
def show_entry_fields():
    print(in_out(e1.get(),e2.get(),key_lst))
    Label(master, text=in_out(e1.get(),e2.get(),api_key)).grid(row=2)

master = tk.Tk()
Label(master, text="Latitude").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Logitude").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Output: ").grid(row=2)


e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
# Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)


mainloop( )
```

When I run this code, I am getting the following,

[image]

The image is displayed in the iPython notebook.

I want the image to be shown inside the Tkinter app. I have tried several things to solve this problem, but it is not working for me. Can anybody help solve this issue ? any leads would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see what line of code would display that map *anywhere*, let alone inside the dialog?

Comment: @usr2564301 display(im(requests.get(url).content)) line displays the map in the iPython notebook and when I enter the lat long in the dialog box, the maps are displayed in the iPython Notebook. I tried several things to bring it into the dialog and those didnt work. So I didnt include those here.